# Access a variable from an non associated Controller in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am developing a quiz using a 'form' in cakephp.  I have declared a variable within my CourseModules controller  ($passMark) where the HR developing the quiz can set the pass percentage the user needs to successfully complete the quiz.  I have declared the variable like so:

```
            case "Quiz":
            $quiz = $this->CourseModules->FormTemplates->find('list')->where(['active'=>true,'type'=>'Quiz']);
            $passMark = [100=>'100%',90=>'90%',80=>'80%',70=>'70%',60=>'60%',
            50=>'50%',40=>'40%',30=>'30%',20=>'20%',10=>'10%',0=>'0%'];
            $this->set('passMark',$passMark);

            $this->set('quiz',$quiz);
            break;
```

I then need to access the variable $passMark within my FormsController so that I can check it against another variable ($percCorrect).  $percCorrect is declared as so in my Forms Controller:

```
        $percCorrect = $numberCorrect / $numberOfQuizQuestions * 100;
        $this->set('percCorrect', $percCorrect);
```

I want to do an if statement so check in if $percCorrect is < $passMark but I'm unsure how to access $passMark because CourseModules isn't associated with Forms Controller.

I do have another controller called CoursesEnrolledModules that is related so I'm wondering if I can somehow access it through there?

I have the following code in my FormsController to load the CoursesEnrolledModules:

```
        //Check if courses_enrolled_module_id is set
    $courses_enrolled_module_id = $this->request->getQuery('courses_enrolled_module_id');

    //If so make sure it is valid
    if($courses_enrolled_module_id){
        $this->loadModel('CoursesEnrolledModules');
        $coursesEnrolledModule = $this->CoursesEnrolledModules->get($courses_enrolled_module_id,
            ['contain'=>[],
        ]);
        //Pass variable to view so we can show correct back button
        $this->set('coursesEnrolledModule', $coursesEnrolledModule);
        //Also after save we will redirect.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you ask yourself "how do I access one controller from another controller", just stop yourself right there and think about a different option. In this case, you should put your array in a central location accessible by everything that might need it. Include it in the config in your app.php, perhaps, and then reference it with Configure::read(...) anywhere you need it.